# How can I create a database each year and select the year I want for a select and display the records for that year?

Tags: php, html, mysql, cron

It turns out that I need to create databases every year incrementally and automatically with their corresponding fields and tables, since , I need each database to be able to store information regarding the type of year, for example: db2021, db2022,db2023 so successively, and that the records that were made in the year 2021 are from the year 2021, records I mean the records of the database table, the typical record, and that for example with a select, you can select the year you want and the records of that year are displayed, and clearly being a new database the ids of each table start again in 1 since there are no records.

Example of what I have tried :

```
<?php
$db = new Mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database', 3306); //make connection
$db->query('CREATE DATABASE `db' . date('Y') . '`'); // create database
$db->select_db('db' . date('Y')); // select newly selected database
$db->query(file_get_contents('cambio.sql')); // import the sql file into it
```

```
select name="dbName">
   <?php
     for ($year = 2022; $year < date('Y') + 1; $year++) {
        echo '<option value="db' . $year . '">' . $year . '</option>';
     }
    ?>
 </option>
```

Comment: Taking this route is probably the result of a bad architecture otherwise a table would be enough

Comment: or if in any table you have you add a column   'time' and you store time() and you use php functions as data() and verify 2021-2021(last month ,last day 23:59:59)  interval you do not need any years databases (meaning you extract in each table the year's data you need)

Comment: "*import the sql file into it*" This won't work. Consult PHP manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways to do differently:

- Having a timestamp column and in query filtering whith WHERE
  YEAR(date) = '2022'
- Having a column "Year" that you fill with
  YEAR(NOW())
- And many other ways...

Comment: Of course, I made option 1, but they ask me with a select choose the year and then when selecting the chosen year, "reset" the database table to be able to enter new records counting the id to 1 again, so I try to make a new database for each year that is created automatically,   and somehow do a database exchange to initialize those records again to 1 and without them being lost, maybe not the way, but I can't find another

Comment: I don't understand why you need to reset id, but: 
If you don't mind to loose old records, you can use a TRUNCATE TABLE It will erase all rows and reset AUTO_INCREMENT to 1.
You can also COPY TABLE to historize  before TRUNCATE.
But why do you really need to reset Id?

Comment: Apparently they want to ensure that the id records of all successive years are not high and that is why the id is restarted again to 1 so that each year the id is not so high apparently and that it is reset every year